# Where do Spring bean configuration files go in a Maven WAR module?

Tags: spring, maven-2, configuration, servlets, war

I've looked at a bunch of sample projects and I can't seem to tease out a common best practice.  I've seen Spring bean config files sometimes go in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory.  I've seen this in conjunction with with a Servlet definition in `web.xml` like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-stuff</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-stuff-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But I've also seen bean config files included within `web.xml` top level -- i.e. outside of a Servlet.  What does this mean?  Is this for cross-Servlet beans?  Sometimes it's in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory and sometimes it's in `src/main/resources`.   Also I've seen other bean config files defined in WAR modules with just about everything in `src/main/resources`.

I've read and re-read the Spring documentation, but the only convention I found is that by default a Servlet context config file should be in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory named `{servlet-name}-servlet.xml`.

So what's the best practice and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Application contexts in Spring can form hierarchies where child context has access to beans defined in parent context.

A typical Spring MVC web application contains a hierarchy with two levels:

- Root web application context loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`.
  Config location of this context is `applicationContext.xml` by default and can be configured using `<context-param>` named `contextConfigLocation`, i.e. at the top level of `web.xml`. This context usually contains a core application logic.
- Servlet-specifc context loaded by `DispatcherServlet`. Its config location is by default `<servletname>-servlet.xml` and can be configured using `<init-param>` named `contextConfigLocation`, i.e. at servlet level. This context usually contains a Spring MVC-related stuff (controllers, etc) since `DispatcherServlet` is a part of Spring MVC.

The latter context is a child of the former.

If web application doesn't use Spring MVC as a presentation framework, it doesn't have `DispatcherServlet` and its context. Some extremely simple Spring MVC samples doesn't have `ContextLoaderListener` and the root context (however, you need root context for cross-servlet functionality such as Spring Security).

Config files of web application are by default located in webapp's root folder. However, they can be placed in the classpath (i.e. in `src/main/webapp`), in this case they are accessed via `classpath:` prefix. This may be useful if you are going to use some of these files in integration tests without servlet container. Also `classpath:` prefix may be useful when you want to load a config file from a separate artifact, i.e. from a jar file in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Very helpful -- thanks.  Wish this was explained this well in the Spring docs!

Comment: @HDave This isn't Spring specific, it's normal java classloader behavior (the only thing that's spring-specific is the `classpath:` prefix)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is often good style to keep the code, its spring configuration an in a separate JAR that is included into the WAR, such that the WAR is basically empty but for web.xml and the like. This saves you from even asking this question. :-)  You can reference those spring configurations with classpath: prefix.

One advantage of this layout is that you can easily write Unittests that instantiate the complete Spring configuration of the WAR within the JAR. I would not necessarily recommend to use this for actual tests (although you can do integration tests this way), but you get a quick feedback when you accidentially break the overall structure of the config files without having to redeploy the application.

If you really need to put spring configuration files into the WAR (perhaps since it also references beans that are implemented in the WAR itself) I would also put them into the normal resources path /WEB-INF/classes, for the reasons discussed above.

Comment: I agree with this and already have all the module level Spring configuration files in those module JARs -- for exactly the reason you mention...integration testing.   However, there are still WAR level Spring configuration files that I had which create instances to be consumed by the servlet container, etc.  I ended up just dropping them in the {{webapp}} directory.

Comment: @HDave I would put such files into /WEB-INF/classes such that they are also in the classpath. So you can at least unit-test them properly.