# failed to autowired annotation

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

why i always get userDetailDao exception null when executed :

```
package com.springweb.service;

import com.springweb.dao.UserDetailDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

public class UserService implements UserDetailsService
{    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailDao userDetailDao;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String string) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        return userDetailDao.queryForUser(string);
    }

}
```

at my spring security config :

```
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
    <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />        
</security:authentication-provider>

<bean name="userService" class="com.springweb.service.UserService">
</bean>
```

and at my dispatcher context, i already define to scan package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springweb"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your `UserDetailDao` is declared in the `DispatcherServlet` context and therefore is not accessible in the root webapp context where `userService` is declared. So, `UserDetailsDao` should be declared as a bean in the root context.

Also you need `<context:annotation-driven/>` in the root context.

Generally speaking, you have a duplication of beans now - beans are added to the `DispatcherServlet` context by `<context:component-scan>`, and beans of the same classes are manually declared in the root context. This situation should be avoided - you need to specify packages to be scanned by `<context:component-scan>` more carefully.

**See also:**

- [Where do Spring configuration files go in a maven WAR module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703389/where-do-spring-configuration-files-go-in-a-maven-war-module/3703635#3703635) for explanation of the concept of Spring context hierarchy.