# mvc:annotation-driven - do I still need to bind Validators?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have added `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to my Spring configuration, and according to the documentation it will provide:

> Support for validating @Controller inputs with @Valid, if a JSR-303 Provider is present on the classpath. The validation system can be explicitly configured by setting the validator attribute.

From this and other documents, I have taken it to mean that I no longer need to explicitly inject a validator within my controller classes and it will be done automatically. Is this correct?

Currently I need to have the following in my controller:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

Can anyone clear this up for me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. With `<mvc:annotation-driven>` you don't need to inject validator explicitly.

Note that in a typical Spring MVC application you have two application contexts, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703389/where-do-spring-configuration-files-go-in-a-maven-war-module/3703635#3703635) for more details, and `<mvc:annotation-driven>` must be declared in the `DispatcherServlet`'s context.

Comment: But I do have to inject it explicitly, or else the validation doesn't work. What could I be missing?

Comment: @Steve: Make sure that `<mvc:annotation-driven>` is declared in `DispatcherServlet`'s context, i.e. `...-servlet.xml`.

Comment: I usually declare things in `myapp-config.xml`, which is referenced as a `contextConfigLocation` in my `web.xml`. This is because I found that `myapp-servlet.xml` would be executed twice, once by Tomcat and then again by Spring. Breakpoints show that `AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser` is being executed

Comment: @Steve: Updated. To avoid double execution you shouldn't add `myapp-servlet.xml` to `contextConfigLocation`.

Comment: Is it normal to require mvc:annotation-driven in both application contexts? I seem to need it in myapp-config.xml to have the @Controllers work

Comment: @Steve: The typical approach is to have `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in `myapp-servlet.xml` as well as controllers.