# spring security with custom user details

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-security

I am trying to apply security in my spring application using database tables.

What I have so far in my applicationContext-Security is:

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.intan.pedigree.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

 <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

my implementation of userDetailsService looks as follows:

```
    package org.intan.pedigree.service;

import org.intan.pedigree.dao.UserEntityDAO;
import org.intan.pedigree.dao.UserEntityDAOImpl;
import org.intan.pedigree.form.UserEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserEntityDAO dao;
    @Autowired
    private Assembler assembler;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        UserEntity userEntity = dao.findByName(username);
         if (userEntity == null)
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");

        return  assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(userEntity);
    }
}
```

my assembler looks as follows:

```
package org.intan.pedigree.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.intan.pedigree.form.SecurityRoleEntity;
import org.intan.pedigree.form.UserEntity;
//import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
//import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl;
//import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  User buildUserFromUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {

    String username = userEntity.getUsername();
    String password = userEntity.getPassword();
    boolean enabled = userEntity.isActive();
    boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isActive();
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isActive();
    boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isActive();
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (SecurityRoleEntity role : userEntity.getUserSecurityRoleEntity()) {
      authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getName()));
    }

    User user = new User(username, password, enabled,
      accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    return user;
  }
}
```

now the user entity is:

```
    package org.intan.pedigree.form;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name="family_name")
    private String last_name;
    @Column(name="dob")
    private Date dob;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="active")
        @NotNull
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="user_types_id")
    private int user_types_id;
    @Column(name="confirm_password")
    public String confirmPassword;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_address", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_id") })
    private Set<Address> userAddress = new HashSet<Address>(0);
    /*******************************************************************************/
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_security_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "security_role_id") })
    private Set<SecurityRoleEntity> userSecurityRoleEntity = new HashSet<SecurityRoleEntity>(0);

    public Set<Address> getUserAddress(){
        return this.userAddress;
    }

    public void setUserAddress(Set<Address> userAddress) {
        this.userAddress = userAddress;
    }
    /*****************************************************************************/

    public Set<SecurityRoleEntity> getUserSecurityRoleEntity(){
        return this.userSecurityRoleEntity;
    }

    public void setUserSecurityRoleEntity(Set<SecurityRoleEntity> userSecurityRoleEntity) {
        this.userSecurityRoleEntity = userSecurityRoleEntity;
    }


    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }
    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public int getUser_types_id() {
        return user_types_id;
    }
    public void setUser_types_id(int user_types_id) {
        this.user_types_id = user_types_id;
    }


}
```

my userentitydao interface is:

```
package org.intan.pedigree.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.intan.pedigree.form.UserEntity;


public interface UserEntityDAO {
    public void removeUserEntity(Integer id);
    public List<UserEntity> listUserEntity() ;
    public void addUserEntity(UserEntity user) ;
    public void updateUserEntity(UserEntity user) ;
    public UserEntity getUserEntityByID(Integer id);
    public UserEntity findByName(String username);
}
```

and implementation is:

```
    @Repository
public class UserEntityDAOImpl implements UserEntityDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addUserEntity(UserEntity user) {
        try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public UserEntity findByName(String username) {
        UserEntity user = (UserEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "select u form user u where u.username = '" + username + "'");
        return user;

    }

    public UserEntity getUserEntityByID(Integer id) {
        UserEntity user = (UserEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "select u form user u where id = '" + id + "'");
        return user;
    }
    public void updateUserEntity(UserEntity user) {
        try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public List<UserEntity> listUserEntity() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User")
                .list();
    }

    public void removeUserEntity(Integer id) {
        UserEntity user = (UserEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                UserEntity.class, id);
        if (null != user) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
        }

    }
}
```

now when i try to deploy on tomcat i get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.intan.pedigree.dao.UserEntityDAO org.intan.pedigree.service.UserDetailsS
erviceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.intan.pedigree.dao.UserEntityDAO] found
 for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotatio
n.Autowired(required=true)}
```

and not mater what i do I can not figure out what is wrong with it. Any advice would be welcome.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any declaration for the `UserEntityDAOImpl` or `Assembler` beans in your context, and no component scanning to auto-detect it.

You either need to declare them alongside the `UserDetailsServiceImpl`, or add a `<context:component-scan>` somewhere.

Comment: inside my pedigree-servlet.xml i use : <context:component-scan base-package="org.intan.pedigree" /> is this not enough? This should scan everything.. my controllers with @Controller can use services and dao's without problem.. :( – user529065

Comment: @user529065: Spring Security doesn't use the `-servlet.xml` contexts. You need to add the component scan to the root webapp context, i.e. in the same context that the Spring Security stuff is in.

Comment: ok i added component scan and it works now. but may i ask another question please? when i try to log on i get this error from hibernate which seems strange:
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: form near line 1, column 10 [select u form user u where u.username = 'giannisapi']
any clue on this?

Comment: @user529065: That's a new question. Close this one and ask an new one.

Comment: ok let me try to find how to close it..  :) :) thanks for your help

Comment: @user529065: Select your preferred answer by clicking the tick-mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

All dependencies of Spring Security (such as your DAO) should be decalred in the root web application context (`applicationContext.xml` or other XML files configured in `<context-param>` named `contextConfigLocation`), not in serlvlet's conext (`...-servlet.xml`), because core Spring Security beans are declared in the root context, and beans in that context don't have access to beans in the servlet's context.

If you use `<context:component-scan>`, you can follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333390/service-are-constructed-twice/4335438#4335438).
**See also:**

- [Where do Spring configuration files go in a maven WAR module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703389/where-do-spring-configuration-files-go-in-a-maven-war-module/3703635#3703635)

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to define UserEntityDAO in your app context.

Comment: inside my pedigree-servlet.xml i use :
<context:component-scan base-package="org.intan.pedigree" />

is this not enough? This should scan everything.. my controllers with @Controller can use services and dao's without problem.. :(